# AngularJs, calling a $resource from within an Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, interceptor, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have just about given up with this. But I have a `$resource` that uses a `query()` to retrieve a list of items. I then have an Interceptor that runs over those items in order to insert an `$interval`.

The `$interval` at a specific point will then get an item again using the `$resource`'s `get()` function. But its this `get()` that is not working.

The call happens but I cannot get the response back into the template.

```
myServices.factory('Items', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource("/items", {}, {
            'query': {
                interceptor: MyInterceptor,
                url:        "/items",
                isArray:    true
            },
        })
    }]);

myServices.factory('MyInterceptor', function($q, $interval, $injector, $rootScope) {
    return {
        'response': function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response.resource, function (item) {
                 $interval(function () {
                     item.something = 1 + item.something;
                     if(item.something == 10)
                     {                         
                         item = $injector.get("Mine").get({slug: item.id});
                     }
                 });
            });
            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

I thought that this line `item = $injector.get("Mine").get({slug: item.id});` would work, but it doesn't. The new item is not changed in the template.

So I changed it to something like this, which did not work either;

```
$injector.get("Mine").get({slug: item.id}, function(data){
    item = data;
});
```

I have tried with `$q` and `$promise` too, but I had no luck with those either. Finding decent examples on those subjects was tough too.

In short ...... I am using an Interceptor inside a `$resource`, with an `$interval` which then needs to eventually change a single value within an array of values within the `$scope` - how can I get this to work?

Comment: curious if you've tried `$rootScope.$apply()`. Don't think this is a good long term fix , just curious. Also interested in why not using a service method to do the updates instead of doing it in an interceptor

Comment: @charlietfl how would I go about changing the response in a service, rather than in an Interceptor?

Comment: @charlietfl I can see there is `transformResponse`, instead of an Interceptor, but there seems to be no examples or docs on using an `$interval` inside of `transformResponse`. Doing so does not work.

Answer (score 0):

*In short ...... I am using an Interceptor inside a $resource, with an $interval which then needs to eventually change a single value within an array of values within the $scope - how can I get this to work?*

Based on the above statement I will give an answer.

First things first, remove the interceptor. You won't need it. Instead use a service.

Write a service called ProcessedItems.

```
angular.module('app')
.service('ProcessedItems', ['Items', '$q', function(Items, $q){
   return {
     query: function() {
       var defer = $q.defer();
       Items.query()
       .$promise
       .then(function(response){
         angular.forEach(response.resource, function(i)){
           i.s = 1 + i.s;
           if(i.s == 10) {                         
             i = $injector.get("Mine").get({slug: i.id});
             i.$promise.then(function(){
                defer.resolve(response);
             }, function(){
                defer.reject();
             });
           };
         };
       });
       return defer.promise;
     }
   };
}]);
```

After this service is set up, in your controller you can do

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'ProcessedItems', 
function($scope, ProcessedItems){
  $scope.items = [];
  ProcessedItems.query().then(function(pitems){
    $scope.items = pitems;
  });
});
```

What this will essentially do is first process the data completely and then display it in the view.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try tomorrow. I have a quick question, the functionality inside of the `forEach` if that is needed to be used elsewhere, say within a `get` on the service how would I re-use it? Also, you don't use $interval anywhere?

Comment: If you want to reuse the functionality inside `forEach` you can create another service specifically for this operation which would be a better thing to do, and then call that service from within the loop. As far as `$interval` is concerned why do you need it at all?

Comment: I need the value to count up per second.

Comment: Okay, so in that case you should have specified the delay in the `$interval` code `$interval(function( ){    }, 1000)`. Right now the $interval seems redundant.

Comment: But does your example work with an `$interval`, I do not see one in there. I need one in there so the value increments per second. From your code it just increments it once then writes it back to the original property.

Comment: Yes, since I am using `$q` here it will work with `$interval` too.